# Plugins Wordpress Cadastro/Listagem de Usuários

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Bom dia pessoal,

estou começando a usar wordpress e estou tentando fazer as funcionalidades de cadastro e listagem de usuários da aplicação.

Consegui fazer o cadastro com o plugin **Formidable**, mas estou tentando usar o plugin **fixon** para a listagem de usuários cadastros.

**Minha dúvida é a seguinte**:

**Eu posso fazer o cadastro de usuários com um plugin e a listagem de usuários com outro plugin?
Caso isso seja possível, alguém já fez isso com os plugins formidable e fixon?**

Answer (score 0):

Ser possível ou não depende de como o plugin que se queira implementar funciona.
Mas de modo geral você tem isso no mesmo banco de dados então listar algo basta ter uma tabela e usar o Objeto WPQuery. Mas se o objetivo é usar um plugin para listagem acho que esse resolve seu problema: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/